# ASP.NET - Authentication against Active Directory fails because of NativeObject binding

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, webforms, active-directory, credentials

I am working on an academic project, and we have to authenticate against Active Directory Domain Services accounts from a web application.
I have followed this msdn [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.90).aspx), and as specified I changed the ldap path in the `Login_Click()` function.
Everything went fine, but when I tried to login in the web app, I got this:

> Error authenticating. Error authenticating user. Logon Failure:
>   unknown user name or bad password ... at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject()...

Here is the error screenshot:
[Web app's error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGa56.png)

For information, I filled the `adPath` like this (in the `Login_Click()` method):

```
string adPath = "LDAP://DC.datacenter.mex.am.company.net/"
```

And we also tried with this :

```
string adPath = "LDAP://DC.datacenter.mex.am.company.net/DC=datacenter,DC=mex,DC=am,DC=company,DC=net/"
```

The credentials we tried to login with are perfectly valids, because we tested them to access to Active Directory accounts ... But the same credentials don't work from the asp .net web app !!!

I searched everywhere on the net, but came with nothing ...

Has anyone got an idea about that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do authentication via PrincipalContext

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                    yourdomain,
                    UsernameforAD,
                    ADUserPassword)
                {
                    bool isAuthenticated= context.ValidateCredentials(username,password);
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! Unfortunately, it stil doesn't work ... Now I got this error :  The server could not be contacted ... at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String userName, String password)

Comment: did you give parameters properly? UsernameforAD and ASUserPassword parameters are not the credentias of current user they are credentials of ActiveDirectory user.

Comment: Yes I think I did so. But could you please tell me of what the credentials of AD user look like ?

Comment: it is not in a spesific format it is normal username and password for example "user3444" "123456"

Comment: Then it definitely doesn't work ... I tried several valid credentials for Active Directory, but nothing... Could ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider be a solution ?? I've seen a tutorial talking about, but it was for .NET 2.0, so I don't know if it's still available ...